# C# loop where the collection is modified

Tags: c#, loops, collections

Have a loop like this:

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

foreach(Category category in categories)
{
    ...

    if(...)
    {
        Category subcategory = new Category();

        ...

        categories.Add(subcategory);
    }
}
```

Problem is of course that the loop collection (categories) doesn't like to be modified while it's running, but I need to do the exact same things to the subcategories as I do to the categories I have to begin with.

Is the only option to do like this - or is there a smarter way to do it?

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
List<Category> subcategories = new List<Category>();

foreach(Category category in categories)
{
    ...

    if(...)
    {
        Category subcategory = new Category();

        ...

        subcategories.Add(subcategory);
    }
}

foreach(Category subcategory in subcategories)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You really should include a [mcve] when you post a question. I should be able to copy and run your code with minimal effort. Right now your code doesn't compile and that makes testing alternatives difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are editing the collection, the code errors as its in a state that can't be determined.
To work around this, use a for loop instead of foreach, and decrement your count manually like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < categories.count; i++)
{
    ...
    if(...)
    {
        Category subcategory = new Category();
        ...
        categories.Add(subcategory);
        i--;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a level order tree traversal. Consider using a queue:

```
var categoryList = GetMyInitialListOfCategories();

var categoryQueue = new Queue<Category>(categoryList);
while (categoryQueue.Count > 0)
{
    var category = categoryQueue.Dequeue();
    if (WeShouldMakeASubcategoryFromThis(category))
    {
        var subcategory = new Category();
        categoryList.Add(subcategory);
        categoryQueue.Enqueue(subcategory);
    }
}
```